# Check Out, Update, then Check In a File in SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: client-object-model, versioning, version-history

I would like to programatically update a SharePoint file by checkout/checkin.

I have written code that looks like it should do what I want it to do:

```
static void HandleFile(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file, byte[] bytes, Logger<bool> Log)
{
    if ((file.CheckOutType != CheckOutType.None) && Log(true, "Undoing previous Check Out for file: {0}", file.Name))
        file.UndoCheckOut();
    file.CheckOut();
    Log(true, "Successfully Checked out file: {0}", file.Name);
    file.SaveBinary(new FileSaveBinaryInformation { Content = bytes });
    file.CheckIn("Comment", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
    var versions = file.Context.LoadQuery(file.Versions);
    file.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    Log(true, "Successfully Checked in file: {0} (versions: {1})", file.Name, versions.Count());
}
```

However, you can probably guess that it does not work as I anticipate.

The code will update the File with the new data (`bytes`), but will not create a new version of the File (rather, it overwrites it), as my final logging line and a look at the SharePoint Library in my browser will confirm.

I've tried adding calls to `file.ListItemAllFields.Update()` at various places. If I add it before the `SaveBinary` call, I will see the same result I mentioned. If I add it after the `SaveBinary` call, the code will throw an Exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Version conflict.

To me, at least it acknowledges the version in that case.

But, how do I programatically update a file and create an entry in the version history with the SharePoint Client Object Model?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the code, the List/Document Library needs to have enabled the versioning setting(s) as well.

In the SharePoint ribbon, in the *Library* tab, select the *Library Settings* button in the *Settings* area. In the settings page, under the *General Settings* header, you'll see *Versioning settings*. Here, you can select settings for versioning, and if you configure the Library to support versioning the code will work.

Exercise caution with the `CheckInType` value in the `File.CheckIn` function. If your Library supports Major and Minor versions, trying to pass `CheckInType.MajorCheckIn` to the `CheckIn` function will cause an error if you don't also handle some items regarding "publishing". (I have only successfully used `CheckInType.MinorCheckIn` with Major and Minor versioning.)

Answer (score 1):

in case some other stumbles upon the same problem, this it what worked for me. (I updated a field value instead of the file though)

```
item.File.CheckOut();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
item["Sprakkode"] = theValue; //UPDATE OPERATION GOES HERE
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
item.File.CheckIn("", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
item.File.Publish("");
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```